# C/Unix: How to extract the bits from st_mode?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, kernel, c

I am a beginner to Unix programming and C and I have two questions regarding the `stat struc` and its field `st_mode`:

1. When accessing the `st_mode` field as below, what type of number is returned ( octal, decimal, etc.)?

   ```
   struct stat file;
   stat( someFilePath, &file);
   printf("%d", file.st_mode );
   ```

I thought the number is in octal but when I ran this code, and I got the value `33188`. What is the base?

2. I found out that the `st_mode` encodes a 16 bit binary number that represents the file type and file permissions. How do I get the 16-bit number from the above output (especially when it doesn't seem to be in octal). And which parts of the 16-bit digit encode which information?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 8. `printf("%o", file.st_mode );` should get you the (hopefully) familiar octal form of the mode.

Comment: What OS are you developing for?

Comment: I am developing in Mac OS X...

Answer (score 1):

The actual type behind mode_t and how it encodes information is implementation defined. The only thing that's certain is that it's a bitmask.

To work with st_mode, use the flags and macros defined in the sys/stat.h header. For a list of those defines, consult:

```
man 2 stat
```

If you truly need to know what each bit represents, or are simply curious, read the header or use printf to inspect the flags.